# Null record Date field displays todays date

Tags: visualforce, sobject

I have a VF page where I am rendering out some subscription information and a couple of the fields are date fields. The issue (sort of) I am seeing is when a record is null and the VF markup calls a date field on that null record it is placing in today's date instead of nothing.

**VF markup:**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
    <apex:outputText value="Upcoming Plan:"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!nextMembership.Start_Date__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!nextMembership.Expiration_Date__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

`Start_Date__c` and `Expiration_Date__c` are `Date` fields, not `Datetime`.

In the controller the value for `nextMembership` is null.

**Debug Image:**

[image: debug image showing value is null]

Line 83 is the same object type as 84, but 83 is not null just to show the object structure.

**Apex Snippet:**

[image: code snippet image]

Just curious what I am missing here? Not a huge issue as I am not even going to render that section if the object is null. But I am really curious why it is showing today's date instead of the empty string???

Comment: Does the field has Default value set at schema level?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava They do not.

Comment: I've personally come across [one situation where JSON serialization returns null](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98099/why-does-json-serialize-return-null-when-passed-a-value-of-type-system-address). What happens when you try to debug `nextMembership` by itself? Are you possibly initializing, cloning, or querying for an instance of `CE_Membership__c` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: I can reproduce it in similar way as author, so there are no trick behind JSON serialization. It is just a weird way of how VF translate controller sobject properties I assume. (even if those are null)

Comment: I think we need to see where you instantiate the `nextMembership` property?

Comment: @DerekF It is null whether or not I serialize it or not.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I never instantiate it. I have a list of them and I assign the list record to `nextMembership` if it meets criteria. I have it declared as `public CE_Membership__c nextMembership {get; private set;}`.

Answer (score 1):

I did some study on this issue and try to reproduce it on my org and it reproduced sucessfully. As per my observation what I found :

1. I think this is due to `<apex:outputfield>`. If you will bind start_date__c  field with `<apex:outputtext>`, it will show actual value of the field, which is blank.
2. On my org I created a new field on Account object, which is numeric, and didn't set default value, not initialize in controller (same as you did), it shows value 0 when I run visual-force page. When I did the same with `<apex:outputtext>` it shows blank value.
3. I think it is possibly some inbuilt functionality, that's why it shows some default value with `<apex:outputfield>` , `<apex:inputfield>`.

Let me know if you are agree with my points.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than keeping the property nextMembership as null, instantiate it with object type. i.e.

```
YourSOBjectAPIName__c nextMembership = new YourSOBjectAPIName__c();

< apex:outputField value="{!nextMembership.Start_Date__c}" />
```

will now show blank rather than today's date.