# Invalid field Address for SObject User

Tags: apex, trigger, dynamic-apex, compound-fields

So, I'm trying to access the `Address` field on the `User` object in an `after update` Trigger but I keep getting the error when I try to update a User record.

> Invalid field Address for SObject User

I am trying to access the dynamically like so.

`... u.get(fieldApiName);`

where `u` is a User object and `fieldApiName` has value `Address`

My handler class has API Version 37.  My trigger was initially API Version 29, but I updated it to API Version 37.  I was hoping that updating the Trigger would resolve the issue but no luck.

I also tried to do it non-dynamically but that doesn't work either.

`u.Address`

Oddly when I try it this way and update the User record I get failed recompilation error.

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger UserTriggers caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: UserTriggers: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: line 4, column 2: trigger body is invalid and failed recompilation: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: UserHandler: line 92, column 82: Invalid field Address for SObject User

It let me save the code, and when I go to Setup > Develop > Apex Class and click on the `compile all classes` link I get no errors. But when I try to update a User record I still get the compilation error.

I would try querying the field via SOQL but I need to get both the new and old values, so SOQL won't help me.

Comment: You must have a hard-coded reference for it to throw an invalid trigger body error, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Correct.  Only when I hard code it does it give the invalid trigger body error.  When I do it dynamically I only get the `Invalid field Address for SObject User` error

Comment: Did you check that your running user has read permission on that field?

Comment: @AdrianLarson So your question lead me to the answer.  I do have read/edit permissions on the field (I am Sys Admin, and runnig user).  My handler class had `with sharing`, once I changed it to `without sharing` it worked.

Comment: Not an ideal fix. You should try moving the logic to an inner class at least to minimize the amount of code you run `without sharing` if you can't find a better workaround.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Actually cancel that.  It didn't fix it. I messed something up in my code that ended up skipping that line.  It is still erroring.

Answer (score 2):

The compound `Address` fields have always been really flaky for me.

I tried to use it in an Apex class that I was developing around a year ago, (ended up in me [discovering a bug in the JSON encoder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98099/why-does-json-serialize-return-null-when-passed-a-value-of-type-system-address)) and it would constantly give me errors about the field not existing, and dependent classes needing recompilation.

As far as I can tell, to actually be able to use one of the compound fields, everything accessed directly and indirectly from a piece of code that uses one of these compound fields needs to have an API version of 30 or greater (which is when these compound field types were introduced).

It's a chore to figure out exactly what ends up being executed, and updating the API version in a production environment requires a deployment.

I'd just stick with the individual fields if at all possible. For the `User` sObject, these are:

- Street
- City
- State
- PostalCode
- Country

Comment: Not exactly ideal as I did also want to capture Latitude and Longitude from the `Address` field.  However this will be my fall back if I can't get Address to work.

Comment: `Latitude` and `Longitude` are also available as separate fields. Those are the API names, so `User u = foo; u.Latitude = bar;` will work.